# How to use CoreImage API to do simple Matrix Operations?

Tags: opencl, core-image, gpu

As we know, 2018, Apple's OpenCL in the iOS environment is not using GPU to calculate. But, the CoreImage API does.

My question is: Is it possible to use CoreImage APIs to do some simple Matrix Operation calculations?

Translate big matrix data into a fake image. Then, use the CoreImage API to process the fake image. After that, convert the fake image back to matrix data.

Is this possible? And, how?

Comment: Probably not. Here's what CoreImage *does* at it's deepest level - you can write a `CIKernel` that returns a `vec4` and works with either a pixel-by-pixel or a *region of interest* basis. How would you **expect** such a framework to do what you want? Use `OpenCL` instead. Yes, it *can* be done.

Comment: For GPU based matrix operations, take a look at Metal Performance Shaders: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/matrices_and_vectors